# How to write to a csv file on the local file system using PySpark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, file-writing

I have this code where I am writing to a csv file on local filesystem but I get error as - `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file:///folder1/folder2/output.csv'`

```
columns = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data1 = rdd1.map(lambda row: [row[i].encode("utf-8") for i in columns])
data1_tuple = data1.map(tuple)

with open("file:///folder1/folder2/output.csv", "w") as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter = ';')
    for (r1, r2) in izip(data1_tuple.toLocalIterator(), labelsAndPredictions.toLocalIterator()):
        writer.writerow(r1 + r2[1:2])
```

On my local filesystem the following directory exists - `/folder1/folder2/`. Why is it throwing this error and how can I write to a csv file on the local filesytem at a specific directory?

Comment: Check whether you have permission to write that folder?

Comment: `open` doesn't take a URI which `file:///...` is, you need to provide a path, e.g. `'/folder1/folder2/output.csv'`

Answer (score 1):

`path` argument for open is

> either a string or bytes object giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or an integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped

not an URI. It means your code should look as follows:

```
with open("/folder1/folder2/output.csv", "w") as fw:
    writer = csv.writer(fw, delimiter = ';')
    ...
```